# `WKWebView` not loading images when `navigationDelegate` is set

Tags: swift, image, wkwebview, assets

I've been trying to integrate payment with MobilePay in my app. I am getting a url from my server (`https://sandprod-products.mobilepay.dk/`) and I load it in a `WKWebView` element.

The problems is that images are not loaded, but oddly enough only when I set `navigationDelegate`, which is a must for me.

[image]

My `navigationDelegate` implementation:

```
extension PaymentsWebViewWrapperViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
                 decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction,
                 decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        guard let url = navigationAction.request.url else {
            decisionHandler(.allow)
            return
        }

        // transaction was completed if it is equal
        guard url.absoluteString != redirectUrl else {
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
            delegate?.didFinishAuthentication(pendingOrder: pendingOrder)
            return
        }

        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
}
```

EDIT: I've changed the implementation to be

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
             decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction,
             decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    decisionHandler(.allow)
}
```

And it doesn't work. If I set the navigationDelegate but do not implement any method, the images are loaded.

What I've tried so far is adding following to `info.plist`

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>sandprod-products.mobilepay.dk</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
      <true/>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

That didn't help, as you can guess. Any suggestions?

Comment: What's your `WKNavigationDelegate` implementation?

Comment: Could you get into `decisionHandler(.cancel)`? I know it's not a redirection per se, but maybe there is one. Maybe print all `url` to see if you see an image one?

Comment: You are the one saying cancel. How do you know that's not the issue? Does it work if you change cancel to allow?

Comment: I just changed implementation to always allow immediately, doesn't work. However, if I set the navigationDelegate but do not implement any function (they're all optional) it works.

Comment: Can you avoid the use of WKWebView? Or is there anything about its configuration you have not told us?

Comment: I have to use it to track the urls loaded. When the redirect url is loaded I dismiss the screen.

Comment: I'd go then by implementing each delegate method, and "allow" the items? Maybe there is one that's blocked, but it's indeed a strange issue, since I'd expect them to allow evertyhing by default. Then go back and block each one of them until you find the culprit. But currently, I don't see what could be the issue, except if to show an image, there is "executing code", and no a simple "display".

Comment: What's more, for other payment methods (Paypal, iDEAL) there is no issue at all